# JavaScript Looping in Nested Array (newbie)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner following a Web Dev Bootcamp video by Colt Steele on Udemy and decided to venture further on JavaScript. Wanting to learn more about querying better through nested Arrays. I wrote the below syntax this morning and want to see if I can use the loop I made to hold the "numbers" pertaining to each player in a variable after the loop? Let me know what you professionals think! I am also open to learning any method or course that you would recommend me to take to further polish my coding skill!

The function below only prints each single argument out from the array declared in the Players variable. I want to use that result to only target the number into a "var" after looping. Sorry if this doesn't make any sense but I feel like there has to be a way to do that haha

```
var players = [[["Lebron James","23"],["Kevin Durant","35"]],
           [["Dwayne Wade","3"],["Russell Westbrook","0"]]];

function loop(){
  for(var i=0; i<players.length;i++){
    for (var k=0; k<players[i].length; k++){
    for (var m=0; m<players[i][k].length; m++){
          console.log(players[i][k][m])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, sure. What would you want your variable to contain at the end? Are you trying to create an array like [23, 35, 3,  0]?

Comment: So right now the whole function is printing out: Lebron, 35, Kevin Durant, 35.. etc in that order but instead of console logging (I just wanted to console log to see if my iterations were working, it is because it seems to be looping into every index of the Arrays). But i want extract the numbers and store them in a variable, as an exercise.

Comment: It just isn't clear what you want the result to be.

Comment: Sorry i hit enter too fast earlier lol.. basically instead of console.log.. i wanted to extract the numbers that pertain to each player into a variable by using all the loops i made. it sounds funny, i know.. lol. wondering how the pro's would do it. haha

Comment: Sure, but when you say "a variable", what did you have in mind? Do you want a variable that contains "232530" (the numbers all smashed together)? Do you want an array variable that contains the four numbers? Do you need to keep the names too?

Comment: Great question! I initially wanted to store each number in a new Array and then create new variables for each one? its more of practice for me because I feel like understanding how to manipulate and iterate Arrays and Objects is big portion of this. Let me know what you think!!

Comment: In a real-world scenario, how you store it is going to depend on how you want to use it. If the intent is to flatten the nested arrays into a single collection of just the scores, then a new array of numbers makes sense. If the intent is to flatten the nested arrays into a structure that lets you list the  players and their scores, then you might want to end up with an array of objects:
`[{"player": "Lebron James", "score": 23}, {"player": "Kevin Durant", "score": 35}, {"player": "Dwayne Wade", "score": 3}, {"player": "Russell Westbrook", "score": 0}]`

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to be able to look up a score by player, then you might want a single object that maps the player to the score:
`{ "Lebron James" : 23, "Kevin Durant" : 35, "Dwayne Wade" : 3, "Russell Westbrook": 0}` This is smaller and allows a lookup -- but doesn't allow plucking out a particular pair of data and handling it in a generic way.

Any of these can be created from your loop -- as in the answers below, you define the variable at the top, and then add each item to the variable in the middle of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to get the numbers from that array? Then you almost got it.

Declare an empty array `const numbers = []` and then add a number in your inner loop. The element `players[i][k]` is the array `[name, number]` for a player. So `players[i][k][1]` is the number you want. Push that into your numbers array

```
function loop(){
  for(var i=0; i<players.length;i++){
    for (var k=0; k<players[i].length; k++){
       numbers.push(players[i][k][1])
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of the `for(...)` loops you could use a `forEach` loop on the array

```
players.forEach(group => {
   group.forEach(player => {
      numbers.push(player[1])
   })
})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Michael,Thank you for your reply. I kept trying your idea but unfortunately when I ran it, it only gave me number 23. I might be making this harder than it should be. But I wanted to try to designate specific values in heavily nested Arrays would work.. I am still playing.. part of the progress right? haha

Answer (score 0):

Although this maybe a bit far ahead, it still might be useful to you later on. Arrays have a multitude of methods which loop over all the items that are inside of it. Each method has a different purpose and outcome.

I've tried to make it as short as possible and used [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to make it work.

```
const numbers = players.flatMap(group => group.map(player => player[1]));
```

Or more verbosely written:

```
const numbers = players.flatMap(function(group) {
  return group.map(function(player) {
    return player[1];
  });
});
```

`map` loops over all the items in the array and creates a new array with the same amount of keys, but with new values that have been returned by the callback function.

`flatMap` does the same but is essentialy a combination of `map` and [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). 
 `flat` can turn an array with for example `[['hey'],['bye']]` into `['hey', 'bye']`. Removing levels of array depth and getting all the values inside the same array.

Both the methods return their values into a new array. So the line below extracts the values from the array and stores them in the `number` variable. Or constant in this case.

Keep practicing and try all of the methods out. They can really help out an make working with arrays much easier. Check out [the docs of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to see what options you have.

Comment: Thank you Emiel - appreciate the veteran response. I might be making this harder than it should be but i am trying my best to not use any other method other than the typical "for" loops to iterate through the nested Arrays to get to the numbers for each player. Kind of awkward to use NBA players' numbers but it was the straight forward practice approach for me. I split the Array up as well to KD and Lebron being the top tier array so that makes me want to loop through it more haha!